# is it possible to know trigger checkbox or item text when using CheckboxListTile in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using CheckboxListTile to show some todo item in flutter(`v3.0.4`). This is the code looks like:

```
CheckboxListTile(
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              title: Text(element.name,style:element.isCompleted == 1? TextStyle(color: Colors.grey):TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              value: element.isCompleted == 1?true:false,
              checkColor: Colors.green,
              selected: element.isCompleted == 1?true:false,

              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                if(value!){
                  element.isCompleted = 1;
                }else{
                  element.isCompleted = 0;
                }
                TodoProvider.updateTodo(element).then((value) => {
                  TodoProvider.getTodos().then((todos) => {
                    buildTodoItems(todos)
                  })
                });
              },
            ))
```

when the user tap the CheckboxListTile item text, I want to show the todo detail information, when the user tap the checkbox, I want to make the todo task changed to complete. Now I am facing a problem is that I could not detect which part the user tap, all the way will trigger onchange event. I have already read the CheckboxListTile source code, seems no api to do this. Am I misssing something? what should I do to detect which part the user select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `title` in a `GestureDetector()`. Now when the title is tapped, *only* the gesture detector will be run, and not the `onChanged()`.

In this example, if you tap on the text "Checkbox" then you can see the actual checkbox value is not being updated but the GestureDetector *is* being called, and if you look at the console "tapped" is being printed.

[image]

Here is a complete example. I hope you understand:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _value = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: GestureDetector(
        child: Text('Checkbox'),
        onTap: () {
          print('tapped');
          // you can change the value here too
          // setState(() {
          //   _value = !_value;
          // });
        },
      ),
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          _value = value!;
        });
      },
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed to using listtile + checkbox. @MendelG